# Wifi not working toshiba satellite c855-1w7 ubuntu12.10

Tags: wireless, realtek

I am very new to ubuntu and have tried following other threads to resolve this issue but keep getting errors would someone be able to guide me step by step

Comment: I have done the command to find out what wireless i have this is what i get [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8723].I then went through getting the driver as shown in this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2040656

Comment: I have downloaded the file as indicated but when i do the cd ~/Downloads/rtl_92ce*2013 i get no such file,when i check the downloads folder the file is called linux_mac80211_0012.0207.2013 tar.bz2

Comment: @richard Open file manager, got to Downloads right-click the archive (the .tar.bz2 file) and choose "extract here", then `cd ~/Downloads/rtl_92ce*2013`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the step by step guide is in the thread you posted.

*Install packages needed for the compilation*

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

notice that the ticks around `uname -r` are backticks like this ` and not quotes like this '

*Download the driver*

Go to this [Realtek site](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true). Scroll down to the unix(linux) section and download the driver from a mirror close to you and save it in your `Downloads` folder. Make sure it's for kernel 2.6.24 and later, see screenshot.
[image]

Navigate to your `Downloads` folder, right-click on the downloaded archive and select "extract here".

*change into the driver directory*

```
cd ~/Downloads/rtl_92ce*2013
```

*change user to root/administrator*

```
sudo su
```

*compile the source code*

```
make
```

*install the compiled driver*

```
make install
```

*load the driver module*

```
modprobe rtl8723e
```

*logout root account, and become normal user again*

```
exit
```

reboot.

Comment: Thankyou for your help I ran the first command and here is the output richard@richard-SATELLITE-C855-1W7:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r`
[sudo] password for richard: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
linux-headers-3.5.0-25-generic is already the newest version.
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:

Comment: The second command seems to do a lot but lots of errors with cannot open file file exsists

Comment: errors when doing make command make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/build M=/home/richard/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012 modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-25-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/richard/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.o
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create /home/richard/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/.tmp_base.o: Permission denied
/home/richard/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c: In function ‘_rtl_init_mac80211’:

Comment: /home/richard/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6: error: ‘IEEE80211_HW_BEACON_FILTER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/richard/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c:320:6: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/home/richard/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012/base.c: In function ‘rtl_tx_agg_stop’:

Comment: let's try a more recent driver, clean up your package installation and run make as root. run `sudo apt-get autoclean` then `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` finally `sudo apt-get update`. Redo the steps in the revised answer with the newer driver.

Comment: if you run into errors again, go to the top of this page, click the edit icon below your question and dump all your error messages there. It's much more readable that way and you can actually post the complete error messages.

Comment: You're welcome. If it's solved check the tick next to the answer and enjoy linux-land. You have stared the beast straight in the eye and killed it. You compiled and installed from source. You are now officially a fearless and magnificent neckbeard.